# Recommended graduate book for perturbation theory

Tags: book-recommendation, perturbation-theory

I'm mostly interested in perturbation theory for linear algebra problems (such as finding eigenvalues) but any book on the subject can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The f

The  following classic text seems to be a perfect fit:

Tosio Kato:
"  Perturbation Theory  for Linear Operators  "   Springer

Comment: This is a nice book. However, the first part of the section 1 of the chapter 2 is really difficult to follow. The author refers to the concept of "algebraic singularities" without defining it. This make it difficult to understand. Also the subsection 2.1.2 is difficult to follow. These part are refereed to the behavior of the roots of a polynomials with respect to the parameter dependency of its coefficients. I'd see a book that explain this part better.